# Use map to create HTML ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects.

```
notifications = [
{notification:"this is notification1"},
{notification:"this is notification2"},
{notification:"this is notification3"},
]
```

Ive been trying to map through the array and create HTML code out of it.

```
 return (
      <div>
      {notifications.map(function(notificationItem) {
        <a> {notificationItem.notification} </a>
      })}
      </div>
    );
```

Can somebody please tell me what is the mistake in this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `.map` you should return value - add  `return` statement to `.map`., also in this case you should add `key` property for each element., because child elements should have unique keys., you can read more about reconciliation [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html)

```js
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    const notifications = this.props.notifications
      .map(function(notificationItem, index) {
        return <a key={index}> {notificationItem.notification} </a>;
      });

    return <div>{ notifications }</div>;
  }
});

var notifications = [
  {notification:"this is notification1"},
  {notification:"this is notification2"},
  {notification:"this is notification3"},
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App notifications={ notifications } />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'd also add that if you don't need stateful React, you could also write your component in this style:

```
const notifications = [
   { notification: "1" },
   { notification: "2" },
   { notification: "3" },
];

const App = function({ notifications }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        notifications.map((item, index) => <a key={index}>{item.notification}</a>)
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <App notifications={ notifications } />,
   document.getElementById("app")
)
```

Comment: My code is very complicated. I just posted a sample code